# How to upgrade Python3 to the latest version on Synology DSM?

Tags: python-3.x, synology, installation-package

Problem: How to upgrade current Python3 to the latest version?

Environment:
Server is a Synology NAS Model DS216+, DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4. Client is a Win 10 PC using SSH to access server via command prompt.

Have Tried:

1. Use Synology's Package Center installed Python 3.5.1, but can not upgrade to higher version, so uninstalled it and rebooted server.
2. Followed Synology forum article and installed ipkg: https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/127148
3. Use ipkg to install Python 3.7.1: "ipkg update"; "ipkg install python3"
4. Then installed pip: “wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py”; “python3.7 get-pip.py”
5. Created symbolic link to Python3: "ln -s python3.7 python3"
6. Now when I type "python3", the version shows: "Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 15 2018, 22:12:17)"

But this is still not the latest version of python 3.8.2. How can I install 3.8.2 on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try installing entware which is very similar to ipkg (sorry, i only have a french link https://www.skyminds.net/nas-synology-installer-entware-ipkg-applications/).

When installed, just run `opkg install python3` and you will have python 3.8.3 on your DS216+ (I run python 3.8.3 on my DS918+).

Then, install pip with `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and `python3.8 get-pip.py`.

To use it, type `python3.8`

Good luck and have a great day !

Comment: Worked for me, since I dont understand french i've troubleshooting using this https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS